# My HTML/CSS Isn't Working - (li not showing)

Tags: html, css, html-lists

```
    float: left;
    display: inline block;
    padding: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    float: left;
    display: inline block;
    padding: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: gray;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

/* Main Menu START*/

.Home {
    float: left;
    display: inline block;
    padding: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.Analyser {
    float: left;
    display: inline block;
    padding: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.Tag-Generator {
    float: left;
    display: inline block;
    padding: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.Link-Shortener {
    float: left;
    display: inline block;
    padding: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.Promotor {
    float: left;
    display: inline block;
    padding: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.Leaderboards {
    float: left;
    display: inline block;
    padding: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* Main Menu END*/

/* Version Menu START */
```

When i remove the "li {attributes}" in the CSS it doesn't seem to work with all the .home .analyser, why is this?

E.g. it should work with the

```
li {
    float: left;
    display: inline block;
    padding: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

But it doesn't i've tried doing li .home {attributes} but it's not seemed to work for me.

Comment: pl provide jsfiddle link

Comment: Inline block should have a hyphen: `display:inline-block` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Provide a JSfiddle, please.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the hyphen in the value of the `display` property. It should be:

```
display: inline-block;
```